# ImportError: No module named rospkg

Tags: ros, python, rospkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm trying to compile a rospackage, but I throws the following error:

> ImportError: No module named rospkg

I checked if it is installed:

> sudo apt-get install python-rospkg    ->   python-rospkg is already the newest version.

> dpkg -L python-rospkg    ->   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

And if that is in my python path:

> echo $PYTHONPATH
> ->  /home/ruud/Dropbox/ros/catkin_workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

The problem looks very similar to http://answers.ros.org/question/44669/fuerte-no-module-named-rospkg/

As far as I see 'rospkg' is **not** inside /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7

Help! :)
Ruud

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212645/importerror:-no-module-named-rospkg/) by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2015-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue by:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/ros/rospkg.git
$ sudo python setup.py install --user
```

Apparently rospkg was not installed properly? Still not sure what is the cause though..

---

Originally posted by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) with karma: 212 on 2015-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-01**:
Hm. If at all possible, I'd avoid using distutils / setuptools to install `rospkg`. I've seen way too many installs (of ROS) freak out after some time. It's probably better (but more involved) to figure out why the debian pkg doesn't seem to be working for you.

**Comment by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on 2015-07-02**:
Yes I prefer to find the cause here. Currently it is fixed, but I did not learn a lot from it..  :)